# Number guessing game to 1-100

Tags: list-manipulation, game

My code is

```
DynamicModule[{n, guess = 0}, 
    {
     InputField[Dynamic[guess], Number], 
     Dynamic[If[n == guess, "You won", "Try again"]],
     Dynamic[n] (* for debugging *)
    }, 
 Initialization :> (n = RandomInteger[{1, 99}])]
```

but there are some problems. The number changes every time and doesn't refer to "you came close" or "decrease" or "increase".

I want to write code that directs me with hints. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this, with tolerance plus minus 5 and a SeedRandom to control the random numbers?

```
DynamicModule[{n, guess = 0}, {InputField[Dynamic[guess], Number], 
  Dynamic[Which[n == guess, "You won", guess < n - 5, 
    "Increase try again", guess > n + 5, "Decrease try again", 
    n - 5 <= guess <= n + 5, "you came close"]], Dynamic[n]}, 
 Initialization :> (SeedRandom[32]; n = RandomInteger[{1, 99}])]
```

@[Hazal](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/79915/hazal): In your initial question you didn't say that you also want the inputs to be refreshed. For this requirement, I have used Manipulate and added a "New Game" button in order the user to be able to start a new game even in the middle of their current game

```
Manipulate[SeedRandom[36 + sr]; n = RandomInteger[{1, 99}]; 
 Which[n == Guess, "You won", Guess < n - 5, 
  "Increase try again\nInput:" <> ToString[n], Guess > n + 5, 
  "Decrease try again\nInput:" <> ToString[n], 
  n - 5 <= Guess <= n + 5, 
  "you came close\nInput:" <> ToString[n]], {Guess, 0},
 {sr, 0, ControlType -> None},
 Button["New Game", sr = RandomInteger[{0, 10000000}]], 
 ControlType -> InputField]
```

Comment: Thank you very much I ran the code. but but the number is not refreshed after reaching the correct guess. how can i fix this